# filling a text-field with click-event-information

Tags: javascript, html

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="text">
  <button id="t-1" value="1">1</button>
  <button id="t-2" value="2">2</button>
  <button id="t-3" value="3">3</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {

    $('#wrapper').click(function(event) {

      $('#text').append(event.target.value);

    });

  });
```

Clicking the button does not change the text-field-value!

Comment: this adds text as `<input type="text" id="text">1</input>` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wrapper').click(function(event) {    
      $('#text').val(event.target.value);
    });
});
```

Remember `append` is to add HTML content, whereas `val` is to get and set the input field value.

Answer (score 0):

[`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) adds HTML content after the input. What you are looking for (changing the text of the input) is [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `val()` to set value of a textbox. `append()` is used to append a DOM element into another element (like appending dynamic `li` into `ul` tags). Below is a working snippet

```js
$(function() {
    $('#wrapper').click(function(event) {
      $('#text').val(event.target.value);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="text">
  <button id="t-1" value="1">1</button>
  <button id="t-2" value="2">2</button>
  <button id="t-3" value="3">3</button>
</div>
```